# Python function that will return a count (int) representing the longest consecutive sequence of positive numbers in array

Tags: python

> The return value must be 0 or positive representing the length of the
>   sequence. Let's call the function `longestSequencePos()`, with one
>   argument (`nums`).

And if you would comment out each section so I can understand it.

Comment: And let's call this question homework.

Comment: Have you tried this problem at all?

Comment: Actually, it's practice work, not homework. I just want to understand it.

Comment: If you want to understand it then try solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def countLongestSequence(nums):
        countMax=0
        count=0
        for i in range(0, len(nums)+1):
                if i == len(nums) or nums[i] <= 0:
                        if count > countMax:
                                countMax=count
                        count=0
                else:           
                        count+=1
        return countMax
```

Comment: Oops. One line is misindented.

Comment: This could be done with groupby in a single line...

Comment: @JBernardo: Absolutely. `return max(itertools.chain([0], (len(list(x[1])) for x in itertools.groupby(nums, key=lambda x: x >= 0) if x[0])))`

Comment: Yeah, and a big comment what the code is doing :)